# Querying large scale table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bigdata

I have a table with 200 million records. This table is updated per minute and new records added to it. I want to query in format of a group by and sum function for KPI analysis. What is the best way to query the table without performance drawbacks? Currently, I save the result in a separate table and I updated this table with a SQL Server trigger, but it isn't a good way. Is there any other way you can suggest?

Comment: What is wrong with the trigger ongoing sum approach?

Comment: In triggers, you should manage delete, update and insert and it makes your trigger complex and error-prone. I think about something like a view but in better performance and error-free such as SSAS but simpler than it.

Comment: As I understand it, you have a very large table and you also have the need to do an aggregation query against that table somewhat frequently.  One way to avoid the penalty of a full query is to instead use a separate table with a trigger to keep track of running sums.

Comment: Consider an indexed view to materialize the `GROUP BY` aggregation. Post you DDL and query if you need help with that.

Comment: Yes I think about indexed view too, but the source table(s) are OLTP and there are many DMLs in a minute

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2016 or an upper version of SQL Server, you can use 
**[Real-Time Operational Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/get-started-with-columnstore-for-real-time-operational-analytics?view=sql-server-ver15)** approach in order to overcome this type
of issue. Real-Time Operational helps to run analytics and OLTP workloads 
on the same database. In this way, you can avoid the **ETL** process.
**Real-Time Operational Analytics** could be an option for your issue.

Comment: Tnx for a great reply, but considering all side effects I think the best way for us is to create and develop an ETL application

Answer (score -1):

Using another table is a good solution if the events are stored in the second table. You can save events by month, weekly, daily, etc. and calculate the system analysis according to it.